# openSuse 15.2 no python38 pip

Tags: python, pip, opensuse

I upgraded my OpenSuse 15.1 to 15.2.  Which installed python 3.6.x. But there was no pip.  So I tried installing python 3.8.5 from OpenSuse.  Again no pip.
Which reports no pip.  If I type 'python3' I get python 3.8.5.

How can I fix this issue.  I need pip.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the python3-pip package:

https://software.opensuse.org/package/python3-pip